# Why my nested loop dose not do what i want

Tags: x86, nested-loops

```
format PE console
  entry start 

  include 'win32a.inc'

  ;======================

  section '.text' code readable executable

  start:
   
   call read_hex

   mov ebx,eax
   mov ecx,3
   xor eax,eax
   xor edx,edx

  

  loop1:
    
    mov eax,edx
  
    loop2:
      
    inc eax

    
    dec ecx
    jnz loop2

  call  print_eax

  mov edx,eax

   dec ebx 
   jnz loop1



   push 0 

  call [ExitProcess]

  include 'training.inc'
```

I was expecting to print out 3,6,9,c... instead i got 3,3,3,3,3 . why eax dose retur back to zero

Comment: When run using a debugger, what is the *first* instruction that does not do what you expected?

Comment: Seems to me like your outer loop needs to set `ecx = 3` somewhere, since the inner loop will decrement `ecx` until it reaches 0.